# How do I add variable to the POST body of the request

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build a search and filter in react and material-ui. I have already implemented a client-side search. All I need for now is to add **something** to the below to pass a text string in the body of the request. This text should come from a TextField, but I have no idea on how to implement it correctly. If I do, it ends up being undefined when it changes as I can't seem to add it directly when states change. Even if I would get a result by adding a `const`, it usually would only load when the page loads but not on `onInput`.

**The Search :**

```
const SearchBar = ({setSearchQuery}) => (
  <form>
    <TextField
      id="search-bar"
      onInput={(e) => {
        setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
      }}
      variant="outlined"
      placeholder="Search..."
      size="small"
    />
  </form>
);
```

**The export function :**

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])

const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {

const someVariable = "5"

const targeturl = "https://website.com/"+someVariable+"/-1";      

fetch(targeturl, {
method: 'post',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
 })
.then((data) => data.json())
.then((data) => setTableData(data))

}, [])

const rows = tableData; 

...

<div className="dflex jusend">
    <SearchBar searchQuery={searchQuery} setSearchQuery={setSearchQuery} />
</div>
```

I tried adding a function that gets the search string from a TextField, but that doesn't work.

```
fetch(targeturl, {
method: 'post',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
body: getQuery(searchQuery)
 })
.then((data) => data.json())
.then((data) => setTableData(data))

}
```

Comment: How you are changing your `seachQuery`. You can keep `searchQuery` in dependency to run whenever searchQuery changes.

Comment: @charchit I've updated the initial question, hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send `data` in body of `fetch` request and also add dependency in `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {

const someVariable = "5"

const targeturl = "https://website.com/"+someVariable+"/-1";      

fetch(targeturl, {
method: 'post',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
body: JSON.stringify({searchQuery})
 })
.then((data) => data.json())
.then((data) => setTableData(data))

}, [searchQuery])
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I change this, it gives no result. Note that The searchQuery comes from a TextField. As you type in the TextField, setSearchQuery gets the changed value.

Comment: Since you are calling the fetch request in `useEffect` hook without dependencies,So it will only work one time after the `first render`.  Else this will work I am pretty confident.

Comment: I've updated the information in my question

Comment: If it would contain data, it would only work at the beginning when the page is loaded. The TextField is empty. When I type in the TextField, it does not pass the value obtained from searchQuery. It returns empty as it does not pass the updated value of the TextField.

Comment: Instead of `onInput` function use `onChange`

Comment: If I use `console.log({searchQuery});` before the use effect, it is empty. If I use it at the end **within** `useEffect`, it is empty. If I use it after `useEffect` and thereby outside of it, it shows the value of my actual search `TextField` immediately. As I type it it shows the change.

Comment: I have updated the answer, add dependency in `useEffect` like this and try

Comment: it works. thank you! Can you please update your anwer and remove the JSON... It only works with `body: searchQuery` and **not** with `body: JSON.stringify({searchQuery})`

Comment: Yes it will work without that also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245255/discussion-between-cyberion1985-and-shikhar-awasthi).